# Hugo + blogdown: Rendering error with date param

Tags: date, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I have tried to setup a portfolio using blogdown, Hugo with Blackburn theme. Once I rendered the website, the posts are picking up a weird date format. I could not narrow down the source of the error. Any leads on this would be highly helpful. Thanks.

```
[params]
  # Shown in the home page

  # CSS name for highlight.js
  highlightjs = "androidstudio"
  dateFormat = "22 May 2019, 21:34"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is invalid. What you want is:

```
dateFormat = "02 Jan 2006, 15:04"
```

Date formatting in Hugo (and Go Lang) may feel peculiar at first, but the [Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/functions/format/#readout) have helpful examples.

Comment: Yes, I have defined the correct dateFormat right? From where it is picking the wrong format?

Comment: @Prradep - No. You need to replace the value of the `dateFormat` param in your config file with the string listed above.